# Get ads and their image in the same query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the graph API and trying to get a list of ads with their insights and post images.

I don't want to do multiple queries for this as I quickly hit the "(#17) User request limit reached" issue even when I use batch queries.

My current query looks like this:

```
/ACCOUNT_ID_HERE/ads?fields=insights{cpc,reach,spend,clicks,ctr},status,creative
```

Now in order to get the post image, I need to take the creative ID that is returned and use it in another query to pull the post like this:

```
/CREATIVE_ID/?fields=object_story_id
```

Then use the returned story id to pull the picture like:

```
/OBJECT_STORY_ID/?fields=picture
```

Is there any way I can combine these queries to do less requests?

Something like:

```
/ACCOUNT_ID_HERE/ads?fields=insights{cpc,reach,spend,clicks,ctr},status,creative{object_story_id{picture}}'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes there is no `creative` and sometimes `/<object_story_id>` is nil.

Comment: Yes but does that mean there is no way of combining these requests?

Comment: You should be able to at least get story id in the same call `adcreatives{object_story_id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) may work for you. It allows for multiple Graph API calls to be made from a single HTTP request and supports dependencies between those requests. Read over the documentation for details and here's a example curl call of how it *might work* (I've not executed this call so please review against the API documentation and test).

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=...' \
-F 'batch=[
  {
    "method":"GET",
    "name":"ads",
    "relative_url":"/ACCOUNT_ID_HERE/ads?fields=insights{cpc,reach,spend,clicks,ctr},status,creative",
  }, 
  {
    "method":"GET",
    "name":"creative",
    "relative_url":"/{result=ads:$.data.*.creative}/?fields=object_story_id"
  },
  {
    "method":"GET",
    "relative_url":"/{result=creative:$.data.*.object_story_id}/?fields=picture"
  }
]' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @bjeavons but as stated in my question, I'm already using batches and it's causing me to hit this limit. I guess each request in the batch is calculated as a single once.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that this method was also hitting the limit for you. Yes, each request within a batch is considered a single request - "You can also use the Batch API to batch your requests, but note that each sub-request is its own API call, or even multiple API calls in the case of specifying many ids." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting